# AI and Linking it to a circuit

Tags: microcontroller, programming, robotics

I have been building a robotic arm for a while now and finally got onto the actual coding side of things. I have been looking around the internet and I’m trying to build some AI code for the arm. Everyone says to use python but is that possible to put on an AVR chip? How do you guys go about implementing AI on circuits? Any tips and tricks would be great.

Comment: What do you need it to learn? There's an easy-for-beginner [IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/) ( C/C++ based). I suggest you to use the basic first.

Comment: Thanks so much, so it isn’t really possible to do with python?

Comment: No, look at [this](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/python-programming).

Comment: Python is just a programming **language**. You don't have to use it.

Comment: Also this question makes no sense, you don't just build AI code for something, you have a **clear goal** and make code that is smart enough to accomplish it. **What is your goal with your robot arm?** You will probably need to read up on [inverse kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics) rather than AI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to construct an artificial neuron looks like this:

$$y_k = \psi \left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}w_{kj}x_{j}\right)$$

[image]
Source: Wikipedia: [Artificial Neuron](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Artificial_neuron.png)

If you've already trained your system and you don't plan on training in on the AVR then you can take the constants and the topology you can code these up with for loops.

Comment: Artificial intelligence and neural networks are not at all equivalent.

Comment: Most artificial intelligence runs off of artificial neural networks these days. They do have SVM's and other classifiers which do not use a neuron as the basis of their model, most of the 'hot topic' AI these days uses neural networks as a basis. My point is, you can code it up yourself.